# Variable Values are not getting Updated

Tags: c#, variables, methods, console-application

I have 3 class files. First is the Main class, second is the Ship class, and the third is the Skill class. All values are added to my Main class file. I have a method where the parameters should be the value in my Main class. Please see below:

```
public class Skill
  {
    public double _capInc;
    public int bscEng, advEng, expEng;

    // engineering
    public double capInc(int bsc, int adv, int exp)
    {
      if(bsc == 5 && adv == 5 && exp == 4)
      {
        _capInc = 0.48;
      }
      return _capInc;
    }
```

The values of int bsc, int adv, and int exp should be the value of bscEng, advEng, & expEng which was set in my Main class

```
skill.bscEng = 5;
skill.advEng = 5;
skill.expEng = 4;
```

But when I try to run the method in my Ship class, values are different

```
public class Ship
  {
    Skill skill = new Skill();

    public double capacitor;
    
    public double totalCap()
    {
      double _totalCap = capacitor * skill.capInc(skill.bscEng, skill.advEng, skill.expEng);
      Console.WriteLine(skill.bscEng + " bscEng inside totalCap");
      return _totalCap;
    }
```

This is the result when I run my Main class

```
class MainClass
  {
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
      Ship ship = new Ship();
      Skill skill = new Skill();

      skill.bscEng = 5;
      skill.advEng = 5;
      skill.expEng = 4;

      Console.WriteLine(skill.bscEng + " bscEng in Main");
      Console.WriteLine(ship.totalCap());
    }
  }
```

Result:

```
5 bscEng in Main
0 bscEg inside totalCap
0
```

Comment: How do you pass the instance of your `Skill` class to your `Ship` class?

Comment: I put this Skill skill = new Skill(); in my Ship class

Comment: So it's a new instance and therefor new values. You need to pass the skill instance to the ship class somehow. Can you edit your initial question and add the code where you instanciate those objects?

Comment: Original question has been edited. Please advise, thank you.

Comment: @JohnG I tried your suggestion but it gives me an error ship.skill is inaccessible due to it's protection level

Comment: Please be aware the OP deleted their last question **where they were given the exact same advice**. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65070906/variable-value-is-not-updating#comment115038868_65070906

Comment: previous question was not clear that's why I revised it for it to be understandable. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should assign the values to `skill` in your `ship` object.

Example:

```
ship.skill.bscEng = <yourValue>;
ship.skill.advEng = <yourValue>;
ship.skill.expEng = <yourValue>;
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it gives me an error ship.skill is inaccessible due to it's protection level

Comment: The easiest way is using `public` (example: `public Skill skill = new Skill()`) to make your `skill` can be accessed globally. You must create a `set` function to assign it if you don't want `public` your `skill`.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments you need to pass the `skill` object to the `ship` object. I've also added an constructor to both classes. I don't know what you really want to do and the code is weird but here's a working solution:

```
class MainClass
{
   public static void Main (string[] args)
   {
      Skill skill = new Skill(5, 5, 4);
      Ship ship = new Ship(skill);

      Console.WriteLine(skill.bscEng + " bscEng in Main");
      Console.WriteLine(ship.totalCap());
   }
}

public class Skill
{
    public Skill(int bscEnd, int advEng, int expEng)
    {
        this.bscEng = bscEnd;
        this.advEng = advEng;
        this.expEng = expEng;

    }
    public double _capInc;
    public int bscEng, advEng, expEng;

    // engineering
    public double capInc()
    {
        if(bscEng == 5 && advEng == 5 && expEng == 4)
        {
            _capInc = 0.48;
        }
        return _capInc;
    }
}

public class Ship
{
    public Ship(Skill skill)
    {
        Skill = skill;
        capacitor = 1.0; // TODO
    }
    private Skill Skill;

    public double capacitor;

    public double totalCap()
    {
        double _totalCap = capacitor * Skill.capInc();
        Console.WriteLine(Skill.bscEng + " bscEng inside totalCap");
        return _totalCap;
    }
}
```

Output should be:

```
5 bscEng in Main
5 bscEng inside totalCap
0,48
```